# Facebook error code 191

Tags: facebook

I've scoured SO and googed all over the place, and I'm still stuck. I feel a little ridiculous, but I've been banging my head against this wall for a few hours.

Here are my FB app settings:

```
App Domain: name.local
Site URL: http://name.local:4000
```

I'm running a local web server and have a web application up and running.

Authentication works (which seems odd because my redirect_url is the same in both the authentication URL and the dialog/feed URL)

name.local is in my /etc/hosts file and points to 127.0.0.1.

I'm running on port 4000.

This URL doesn't work:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?client_id=nnnnnn&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fname.local%3A4000&name=aname&caption=acaption&description=descr&show_error=true

I get this error message:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

I'm using test users (created using the FB test user API).

I've checked that my Site URL and redirect URL are in unison about a million times.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Site url and app url must be shame .
app url should not contain protocol information .

site url should contain protocol

Answer (score 0):

I love computers, they do exactly what you tell them to :)

I had to use **app_id** instead of **client_id** (that's what I get for copying and pasting from my authorization code).